# My API request keeps using up 25 requests for no apparent reason

Tags: php, html, api

My request functions from PUBG official API

```
<?php

    function getProfile($profile, $div){
      $pubgapikey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
      $id = getID($profile);
      $url = "https://api.pubg.com/shards/pc-na/players/$id/seasons/$div";

      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $pubgapikey, 'Accept: application/vnd.api+json'));
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
      $result=curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);

      $json = json_decode($result, true);
      if($json["data"]["type"] == "playerSeason"){
        return $json["data"]["attributes"];
      }else {
        return false;
      }
    }

    function getID($name){
      $pubgapikey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
      $url = "https://api.pubg.com/shards/pc-na/players?filter[playerNames]=$name";

      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $pubgapikey, 'Accept: application/vnd.api+json'));
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
      $result=curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);

      $json = json_decode($result, true);
      return $json["data"][0]["id"];
    }
```

So That's my function for requesting the data. I'll include the ways I call this.

```
// My index.php file (All requests go through here)    
$page = explode("/", trim($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "/"));

switch($page[0]){
  case "profile":
    require("controllers/search_controller.php");
    $data = getProfile($page[1], "division.bro.official.2018-09");

    if($data != false){
        include("pages/profile.php");
    }else{
        include("pages/home.php");
        echo '<script> document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Cannot find user. Remember To Be Capital Sensitive!"; </script>';
    }
    break;
}
```

I know that I'm using a really dumb way to include pages and what not but I don't wanna use or build my own php framework atm and this works just fine for what I'm doing

```
// Here is my php for calling the function
<?php
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
  $user = $_POST['username'];
  if($user != ""){
    header("Location: http://www.statstreak.us/profile/$user");
    die();
  }
}
?>
```

That's pretty much it. The form is just a basic html form.

For some reason this keeps using up my 25 requests/minute that I got from PUBG which is annoying as I can't find a reason why it would use up more than 2 requests per user

Comment: You mean it's querying the API more times than you're running the script?

Comment: Well yeah I am querying it twice to get the player id but for some reason its running way more times since my quota of 25 requests/minute is running out every time I request it

Comment: It's supposed to query twice for every time the script runs. Are you querying more often than that? Check your server log to see how often the script is running.

Comment: If the script runs more than 12 times/minute then you'll exceed your quota. You need to figure out why the script is running so much.,

Comment: yeah no thats why I posted it here

Comment: If the API calls are more than 2x the frequency of the script, then there must be a loop somewhere in the code, which you haven't shown.